# Upper bound of the derivative of a rational function $\frac{f}{f+g}$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, rational-functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be real nonzero polynomials with *nonnegative* coefficients such that

- the degree of $g$ equals the degree of $f$ plus one, that is $\deg(f+g) = \deg(f) + 1$,
- $(f+g)(0) \neq 0$.

Let
$$
h = \frac{f}{f+g}.
$$
In particular, it follows that $h$ is well defined on the interval $[0,+\infty)$, and
$$
0 \le h(x) \le 1, \qquad x \ge 0.
$$
Even more, using the partial fractions decomposition, we have that there is a constant $C > 0$ such that the $n$-th derivative of $h$ satisfies
$$
|h^{(n)}(x)| \le C \frac{n!}{x^{n+1}}, \qquad x > 0,\ n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

> Is it true that we can choose $C$ as above that does not depend on the coefficients of polynomials $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we can. As a counterexample, take $n=0$ and set $f_k(x)=k$ and $g_k(x)=x$, so that we have a sequence of these kinds of functions:
$$
h_k(x)=\frac{k}{k+x}.
$$
If there were such a $c$, independent of the coefficients of $f$ and $g$, we would have $$
h_k(x)\leq \frac{c}{x},
$$ independently of $k$, that is to say, $x\cdot h_k(x)$ *is bounded indepently of* $k$. However, we have that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\cdot h_k(x)=k,
$$
so this cannot be true (just take $k$ as for example $\lceil c\rceil+1$ and $x$ sufficiently big).

Comment: What a nice and simple example! I thought that it was possible in such a general situation. Does anything change [under stronger assumptions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863392/upper-bound-of-the-derivative-of-fracxfxx2xfx-gx)?

Comment: Thank you! As for your stronger assumptions, I would expect it to hold, my reasoning being that the additional power in the denominator kills this kind of bad behaviour. It definitely works for $n=0$ now, if I have time later, I will check for general $n$.