# Upper bound of the derivative of $\frac{xf(x)}{(x^2+x)f(x) + g(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, rational-functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be real nonzero polynomials with *nonnegative* coefficients such that $g(0) \neq 0$.

Let
$$
h(x) = \frac{xf(x)}{(x^2+x)f(x) + g(x)}.
$$
In particular, it follows that $h$ is well defined on the interval $[0,+\infty)$, and
$$
0 \le h(x) \le 1, \qquad x \ge 0.
$$
Even more, using the partial fractions decomposition, we have that there is a constant $C > 0$ such that the $n$-th derivative of $h$ satisfies
$$
|h^{(n)}(x)| \le C \frac{n!}{x^{n+1}}, \qquad x > 0,\ n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

> Is it true that we can choose $C$ as above that does not depend on the coefficients of polynomials $f$ and $g$?

If this is not possible, are there some "natural" conditions that guarantee the existence of such $C$?

**Note**: This is a follow-up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863349/upper-bound-of-the-derivative-of-a-rational-function-fracffg).

Comment: Do you want $C$ to be independent of $n$ too? I do think we can make it independent of the coefficients, because in the previous question, the function behaved like $f/g$. But here, the important coefficients are "linked together" (or, if $g$ has high degree, we fall off much quicker than $1/x^{n+1}$ anyway). But I am unsure about the dependence on $n$.